# Toggle between multiple font presets

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way toggle the editor between two font presets?

The font I use for editing has very light strokes, so it's not great for screen sharing. So whenever I screen share, I'd like have an easy way to switch multiple font-related settings at once:

- editor.fontFamily
- editor.fontSize
- editor.fontWeight
- editor.letterSpacing

This way I could have a preset for solo editing, and one for screen sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the extension [Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle)

```json
{
    "key": "F11",
    "command": "toggle",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "id": "font",
        "value": [
            {
                "editor.fontFamily": "'Source Code Pro', 'Cascadia Code', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
                "editor.fontSize": "14"
            },
            {
                "editor.fontFamily": "'Cascadia Code', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
                "editor.fontSize": "24"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Add all the other settings you want.